# Nginx Match Image Filename Based On Part of URL?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

For local development, I'm trying to serve static content out of a public directory. My images live in `app/public/images`, and my root is `app/public`. My images are looked up at `/d/my_app_name/images/<image>.png`. I'm matching the `/d/my_app_name/images` location, but trying to figure out how to then extract the file name and have nginx look up the appropriate filename from the images directory? My current settings:

```
    root /app/public;
    index index.php;


    location /d/my_app_name/images/ {
        root /images/; # <--- I guess this rule is making nginx look up a file that matches the entire relative path, rather than just the filename
    }
```

UPDATE
I was able to get it to match and look up the filename only from what appears to be the right directory, but I'm still getting a not found error. I'm assuming that the relative path shown in the error is relative to the root, in which case that file/directory should exist.

```
    root /app/public;
    index index.php;

    location /d/my_app_name/images/ {
         alias /images/;
    }
```

When I go to `localhost:8380/d/my_app_name/images/my_image.png` it is looking up the correct png file in the app/public/images directory, but it's still saying it doesn't exist.

`[error] 8#0: *1 open() "/images/my_image.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.176.1, server: devbox, request: "GET /d/my_app_name/images/my_image.png HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8380"`

Images are kept in `/app/public/images` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have inverted location and root paths.

I can suggest you to change your location block as follow:

```
location /images/ {
     root /d/my_app_name/images/; # override global root to your specific path where your images are hosted
}
```

More configurations examples can be found on the [official documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - the location should match the request path, correct? i.e. I am looking up my images from `localhost:5000/d/my_app_name/images/filename.png`, so the location is matching `/d/my_app_name/images`?

Comment: Misunderstood here, I think you can follow @Sam answer's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple alias which tells Nginx to search for all the files in another path. Root would only work if your location was just images and is actually used in the documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

```
root /app/public; #Use full path, ex: /home/username/repo/app/public/
index index.php;

location /d/my_app_name/images/ {
    alias /app/public/images/; # Use full path, ex: /home/username/repo/app/public/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure this would work (assuming I'm understanding correctly). This needs to be a portable solution that would work on anyone's machine, so I can't hardcode a full path - it needs to be relative to the nginx root.

Comment: I was able to get it to do what I THOUGHT would work, but still not working
`root /app/public;
    index index.php;

    location /d/my_app_name/images/ {
        alias /images/;
    }`
When I go to `localhost:8380/d/my_app_name/images/my_image.png` it is looking up the correct `png` file in the `app/public/images` directory, but it's still saying it doesn't exist. 

`[error] 8#0: *1 open() "/images/my_image.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.176.1, server: devbox, request: "GET /d/my_app_name/images/my_image.png HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8380"`

Comment: I would have to do a lot of digging to see how nginx can do your secondary request. My suggestion is to use the /var/www/html which most nginx installations use by default. Because each computer is different, you can put the static files up there. The full path I think is common enough and supported by alias that I would go with my original answer instead.